# Converting strings to code

Tags: string, python-3.x, function, return, symbolic-math

This is a programming question for Python 3.5

Say I have a string s which I define as

```
s = "a + b"
```

and I have some variables

```
a = 1

b = 2
```

How can I make a function from the string that uses the variables a and b?
s is something that you can arbitrarily enter as a string input.

```
def f1(s):

    ???Code???

    return a + b
```

or

```
s = "a*b"

def f2(s):

   ???Code???

   return a*b
```

Does this involve symbolic programming? Is this even possible?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `eval` function.
https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#eval

Example:

```
a = 2
b = 5
eval('a+b') # 7
```